# Prevent URL without protocol to become relative URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some model and I want to render html-markup in RazorView like this:

```
<a href="@Model.Website">@Model.Title</a>
```

The user can write any url in the `Website` property (`google.com`, `www.google.com`, `http://www.google.com` etc).

The problem is if the user doen't write the protocol prefix, like `http`, then the resulting HTML is seen as a site-relative URL by the browser:

```
<a href="http://localhost:xxxx/google.com">Google</a>
```

Is there any simple solution or do I have to prepare website string (add "http" prefix) before rendering the html?

Comment: Guys, this problem has nothing to do with MVC or Razor, and it [certainly isn't ASP.NET MVC 3 specific](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/what-are-the-guidelines-for-using-version-specific-tags). Please  stop adding those tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't really MVC specific, but you could use the `UriBuilder` class:

```
string uri = "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx";
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(uri);
uriBuilder.Scheme = "http";
Console.WriteLine(uriBuilder.Uri);
```

Prints `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx`.

```
string uri = "google.com";
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(uri);
uriBuilder.Scheme = "http";
Console.WriteLine(uriBuilder.Uri);
```

Prints `http://google.com/`.

Comment: so i cant simply force razor to render this string directly without mapping it to action methods?

Comment: To Razor, your `Model.Website` is a string like any other. It will not magically add `http` (and why not `https?`) in front of it because it happens to be printed in a `href` attrbute of an `a` tag. It's your browser that converts `<a href="google.com" />` to `<a href="http://currentpage/google.com" />` (click _View Source_ in the browser instead of inspecting the DOM to verify this). Either fix it using my code before saving the URL, or see @hutchnoid's answer to prevent an invalid URL to be entered in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `[Url]` attribute for this to enforce users to enter a correct Url.

Add this to your model:

```
[Url]
public string Website { get; set; }
```

And this to your view.

```
 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Website)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Website)
 </div>
```

You can specify a specific message back to the users like this:

```
[Url(ErrorMessage = "You must specify the full url including the protocol i.e. http://www.google.com")]
```